# jquery php image upload using http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

Iam looking for jquery php image upload exactly given in http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.
i tried code given in the above site. but its not working . as iam newbie.. i tried below code.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'c:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-upload\server\uploads\';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  // WARNING! DO NOT USE "FALSE" STRING AS A RESPONSE!
  // Otherwise onSubmit event will not be fired
  echo "error";
}
?>
```

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        body {font-size:13px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; width:700px; margin:100px auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="http://github.com/valums/file-uploader">Back to project page</a></p>

    <p>To upload a file, click on the button below. Drag-and-drop is supported in FF, Chrome.</p>
    <p>Progress-bar is supported in FF3.6+, Chrome6+, Safari4+</p>

    <div id="file-uploader-demo1">
        <noscript>
            <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
            <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
        </noscript>
    </div>

    <script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function createUploader(){
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
                action: '../server/upload.php',
                debug: true
            });
        }

        // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
        // don't wait for the window to load
        window.onload = createUploader;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: can we see your full html code please

Comment: And if you change the first line to  $uploaddir = '/uploads/'; does that work? When using localhost you are access via (i guess) xampp, and the upload dir should also be using your xampp. Have you also tried looking at what the console returns? (with debug true on any errors are logged to console)

Comment: no errors showing in console only below line.................[uploader] xhr - server response received
fileuploader.js:873

Comment: file is uploading ..showing failed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php change:

```
$uploaddir = 'c:\xampp\htdocs\ajax-upload\server\uploads\';
```

to

```
$uploaddir = 'server/uploads';
```

in javascript change:

```
action: 'http://localhost/ajax-upload/server/upload.php',
```

to

```
action: 'server/upload.php',
```

if the php file you are running is in the ajax-upload folder.